# how to validate if body request schema is same as in swagger api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

i need to create a controller that expose checkCustomer service that recive a body of Customer Object and the function check Customer should check if the json schema that i got in the body request is the same like in swagger api documentation and return success or fail i can't find how to do this checking please someone help here is some of my code that i tried :

```
 @Service
 public class CustomerService implements CustomerServiceInter {

  @Override
  public String checkCustomer(Customer customer) throws JsonProcessingException {
    OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPI();
    MessageResolver messageResolver = new MessageResolver();
    SchemaValidator schemaValidator = new SchemaValidator(openAPI, messageResolver);
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = ow.writeValueAsString(customer);
    ValidationReport validate = schemaValidator.validate("customer", json , "prefix");
    System.out.println(validate);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your Customer object is made at the image of the Swagger API right? So what do you want to validate exactly? If the request is not right Spring will throw invalid request.

Comment: i need to check if the json that i get from the request is a valid swagger spec